# Xamarin Android send back to login when app opened

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin android app that has a couple of activities. Every time the user opens the app, they have to input a password and then use the app, we do not persist the login.

One of the things the client raised is that the user should be sent back to login if the app was minimized and they open it again.

How do I achieve this? As far as I can see, each activity has an OnResume function but I cannot tell how to detect if the app is coming from the background? Due to this being a Xamarin Android project, there is no general App.cs class to put this into as well? Do I have to put this on each Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to implement `Android.Arch.Lifecycle` as it is the only true way to handle the whole application entering background and restarting properly (there are numerous hacks dealing with Activity lifecycle methods but this library was written by Google to avoid all the issues that those lead to and supports all APIs since 14(?).

1st: Add the `Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Extensions` nuget package to your app.

2nd: Implement an Android Application subclass in your project, add a `IGenericLifecycleObserver` and register your observer via the `ProcessLifecycleOwner`:

**Note**: You can also implement this within an Activity subclass and then use that subclass as the base class for all your other Activties (beside the Login one of course).

#### Example:

```
[Application]
public class App : Application, IGenericLifecycleObserver
{
    public App(IntPtr javaReference, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer) { }

    bool Stopped;
    public void OnStateChanged(ILifecycleOwner p0, Lifecycle.Event p1)
    {
        Stopped |= p1 == Lifecycle.Event.OnStop;
        if (p1 == Lifecycle.Event.OnStart && Stopped)
        {
            // app is coming back from being in the background, do something...

            Stopped = false; // reset 
        }
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.Get().Lifecycle.AddObserver(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a go in the morning and let you know how I come. Appreciate the assistance

Comment: This does what I need! Thank you! Only issue I had was that it steps inside the if statement on first start up as well so it bypasses a screen I had after my splash activity. I amended the condition to just check if my user != null as it  should only really be resetting the process if they were logged in previously.

Comment: @SashaStojanovic, Its not working with Release Configuration, Please check